# A question about topology, related to the middle part of Wade Introduction to Analysis (4th edition) p.469

Tags: general-topology

Let $R_j$ be a rectangle in (so a connected subset of) $R^n$. And let $E_1$ and $E_2$ are Jordan regions in $R^n$.

Wade's text p.469 says "Since $E_1$ and $E_2$ are nonoverlapping, we may also assume that $$V(\overline{E_1 \cup E_2};\mathcal G)<\varepsilon.\tag{16}$$

Since each $R_j$ is connected and ${E_1}^{\circ}\cap {E_2}^{\circ} = \emptyset$, it is easy to see that $R_j \subset {(E_1 \cup E_2)}^{\circ}$ satisfies one and only one of the following three conditions: (i) $R_j \subset {E_1}^{\circ}$; (ii) $R_j \subset {E_2}^{\circ}$; (iii) $R_j \cap \overline{(E_1 \cap E_2)}\not = \emptyset$."

But there is a counterexample(due to Eric)  against the above:
Let $E_1 =\{(x,y):y<x,\left| x \right|, \left| y \right| \le 1 \}$  $E_2=\{(x,y):y\ge x, \left| x \right|,\left|y \right| \le 1\}$, and $R_j=[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]×[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]\subset (-1,1)×(-1,1)={(E_1\cup E_2)}^{\circ}.$ Then $R_j\not\subset {E_1}^{\circ}$,$R_j \not\subset{E_2}^{\circ}$, and $R_j \cap \overline {E_1\cap E_2} =\emptyset$.

Therefore I think we should correct (16) to $$V(\overline{E_1} \cap \overline{E_2};\mathcal G)\lt \varepsilon.\tag{16*}$$ and (iii) to $$R_j \cap \overline {E_1} \cap \overline {E_2} \not=\emptyset. \tag{iii*}$$
[Note that Jordan regions $E_1 $ and $E_2$ are nonoverlapping iff  $Vol(E_1 \cap E_2)=0$ iff  $Vol(\overline E_1 \cap \overline E_2)=0.$
Indeed, on one hand, since $E_1 \cap E_2 \subset \overline E_1 \cap \overline E_2,$ if $Vol(\overline E_1 \cap \overline E_2)=0,$ then $Vol (E_1  \cap E_2)=0.$
On the other hand, set $\widetilde {E_i}=(\overline E_i \setminus E_i)$ for each $i=1,2$.
Then $\overline E_1 \cap \overline E_2 =(E_1 \cup \widetilde {E_1}) \cap (E_2 \cup \widetilde {E_2})=(E_1 \cap E_2) \cup (E_1  \cap \widetilde {E_2}) \cup (\widetilde {E_1} \cap E_2) \cup (\widetilde {E_1} \cap \widetilde {E_2}),$ which implies ${Vol(\overline E_1 \cap \overline E_2)} \le {Vol(E_1 \cap E_2) + Vol(E_1 \cap \widetilde {E_2}) + Vol(\widetilde {E_1} \cap E_2) + Vol(\widetilde {E_1} \cap \widetilde {E_2})}$

But the right side of the above = 0
because $\widetilde E_i=\overline {E_i} \setminus E_i \subset \overline E_i \setminus \ {E_i}^{\circ}
=\partial E_i, Vol(\partial E_i)=0,$ and $Vol(E_1  \cap E_2)=0.$]

Clearly not both of (i) and (ii) hold. Now if $R_j  \not\subset {E_1}^{\circ}$, $R_j \not\subset {E_2}^{\circ}$,and $R_j \cap \overline{E_1} \cap \overline {E_2}=\emptyset$,then ${E_1}^{\circ}$ and $(R^n \setminus (\overline E_1 \cap \overline E_2))\cap {E_2}^{\circ}$ are disjoint nonempty open sets separating $R_j$, a contradiction.

Can it be right?

Comment: Simply posting a problem statement without showing any of your own attempts to solve it is frowned upon here.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. Can you please [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)?

Comment: If you don't have time to follow the link I gave above, you can open the edit window of your post to look at how @Ricky formatted your initial version, and do the same on the paragraphs you added meanwhile.

Comment: For the record, this does appear to be a slight error in the text; presumably what was intended was "iii) $R_j\cap\overline{E_1}\cap\overline{E_2}\neq\varnothing$". For instance, consider $E_1=\{(x,y): y<x\}$ and $E_2=\{(x,y): y\geq x\}$, with $R_j$ the unit ball. Clearly (i) and (ii) do not hold, but neither does the (iii) in the text since $\overline{E_1\cap E_2}=\varnothing$. It's not clear how much this damages the proof of Theorem 12.23.ii, but you can probably use the measure-zero boundary to change assumption (16) to something that works with this intersection instead.

Comment: Sorry. I should have added that $E_1$ and$E_2$ are Jordan regions and so by definition they should be contained in a rectangle in $R^n$. Your examples are not Jordan.

Comment: Ah, come on mate, that is not a serious objection. Simply cut off the sets at $|x|,|y|\leq 10,\!000,\!000$ or whatever. (Sorry for the brusque tone but I clearly went through the work of digging into the book and in particular brought up the zero boundary assumption.)